# dailyUI: How does the countdown css variable change every second?

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css, daisyui

I'm looking at this [countdown timer](https://daisyui.com/components/countdown/) from daiyUI.

[image]

And looking at the [unstyled css](https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui/blob/master/src/components/unstyled/countdown.css) and [styled css](https://github.com/saadeghi/daisyui/blob/master/src/components/styled/countdown.css) source code for it. I can't find any html or javascript.

```css
/* countdown.css in unstyled folder */

:root .countdown {
  line-height: 1em;
}
.countdown {
  display: inline-flex;
  & > * {
    height: 1em;
    @apply inline-block overflow-y-hidden;
    &:before {
      position: relative;
      content: "00\A 01\A 02\A 03\A 04\A 05\A 06\A 07\A 08\A 09\A 10\A 11\A 12\A 13\A 14\A 15\A 16\A 17\A 18\A 19\A 20\A 21\A 22\A 23\A 24\A 25\A 26\A 27\A 28\A 29\A 30\A 31\A 32\A 33\A 34\A 35\A 36\A 37\A 38\A 39\A 40\A 41\A 42\A 43\A 44\A 45\A 46\A 47\A 48\A 49\A 50\A 51\A 52\A 53\A 54\A 55\A 56\A 57\A 58\A 59\A 60\A 61\A 62\A 63\A 64\A 65\A 66\A 67\A 68\A 69\A 70\A 71\A 72\A 73\A 74\A 75\A 76\A 77\A 78\A 79\A 80\A 81\A 82\A 83\A 84\A 85\A 86\A 87\A 88\A 89\A 90\A 91\A 92\A 93\A 94\A 95\A 96\A 97\A 98\A 99\A";
      white-space: pre;
      top: calc(var(--value) * -1em);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
/* countdown.css in styled folder */
.countdown {
  & > * {
    &:before {
      text-align: center;
      transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. Where is the code/how does the `--value` css variable keep decrementing purely in css?
2. In the countdown.css, on the `content:` line what does `\A` denote? It looks like it denotes a new line from the output but... never seen that before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Where is the code/how does the --value css variable keep decrementing purely in css?**

It's not purely in CSS. It's done in JS.
If you read the [countdown doc](https://daisyui.com/components/countdown/) you've provided, you'll see this sentence:

> You need to change to --value CSS variable using JS. Value must be a number between 0 and 99

I believe that they are using ***svelte*** on their website.

2. **In the countdown.css, on the content: line what does \A denote? It looks like it denotes a new line from the output but... never seen that before**

The `\A` injects a line break. You can find more info in the [W3 specs](https://Authors%20may%20include%20newlines%20in%20the%20generated%20content%20by%20writing%20the%20%22%5CA%22%20escape%20sequence%20in%20one%20of%20the%20strings%20after%20the%20%27content%27%20property.%20This%20inserted%20line%20break%20is%20still%20subject%20to%20the%20%27white-space%27%20property.%20See%20%22Strings%22%20and%20%22Characters%20and%20case%22%20for%20more%20information%20on%20the%20%22%5CA%22%20escape%20sequence.).
To make it work, you will need `white-space: pre;`:

> `pre`
> Sequences of white space are preserved. Lines are only broken at newline characters in the source and at <br> elements.